# select salgrade when sal is given where they both are from different tables and no common column exists between them

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

this is my salgrade table

```
grade losal   hisal
1   700.00  1200.00
2   1201.00 1400.00
3   1401.00 2000.00
4   2001.00 3000.00
5   3001.00 9999.00
```

and this is my emp table

```
sal     empno   ename
800.00  7369    SMITH
1600.00 7499    ALLEN
1250.00 7521    WARD
2975.00 7566    JONES
1250.00 7654    MARTIN
2850.00 7698    BLAKE
2450.00 7782    CLARK
3000.00 7788    SCOTT
5000.00 7839    KING
1500.00 7844    TURNER
1100.00 7876    ADAMS
950.00  7900    JAMES
3000.00 7902    FORD
1300.00 7934    MILLER
```

By using these tables I need to select sal when two grades are given

Comment: I got the solution..select distinct e.empname,e.empno1,e.sal,e.job,e.mgr,e.hiredate,e.comm,d.deptno,d.loc,d.dname,s.grade
from emp e inner join dept d on e.deptno=d.deptno full join salgrade s on e.sal between s.losal and s.hisal 
full outer join salgrade s1 on e.sal between s1.losal and s1.hisal 
where d.loc = 'chicago' and e.hiredate<'01-jul-1981' and (s.grade='2' or s1.grade='1')

Answer (score 1):

You can still `JOIN` using comparisons, which effects an interpolation, e.g. to find all employees in Sal Grade 1:

```
SELECT emp.empno, emp.sal, salgrade.grade
FROM emp
INNER JOIN salgrade
ON emp.sal BETWEEN  salgrade.losal and salgrade.hisal
WHERE salgrade.grade = 1;
```

(You probably want to ensure that the data in `salgrade` covers all salary ranges, and doesn't contradict itself, e.g. remove the duplicates in `salgrade`)

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c22cd/3)

Answer (score 0):

Using stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ProcedureName 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @grade int

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    Declare
    @HiGrade decimal(9,2),
    @LoGrade decimal(9,2)

    select @HiGrade = a.hisal, @LoGrade = a.losal
    from (select distinct grade, losal,  hisal
          from salgrade
          where grade = @grade) a

    select * 
    from Emp
    Where sal between @LoGrade and @HiGrade
END
GO
```